# jScrollPane com jQuery Sortable de 2 listas

Tags: jquery, sortable

Estou montando um *layout* aonde eu tenho duas listas (primeira com 3 itens máximos e a segunda com outros itens), que posso mover itens entre as listas utilizando o `sortable` do jQuery.

A função funciona perfeitamente, até eu colocar o jScrollPane, pois o responsável do *design* quer uma barra de *scroll* diferente. Ai meus problemas começaram.

Ao tentar trocar de listas, o item desaparece pois o jScrollPane coloca `overflow:hidden` e assim não ficando legal a movimentação.

Como no jsfiddle.net ficou ruim, coloquei no meu site http://www.tiedt.com.br/teste/teste.html.

O que posso fazer? Tem alguma forma de fazer um *scroll* personalizado para todos os navegadores?

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({ autoReinitialise: true  });
```

Sortable

```
$('#sort1').sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        var li = $('#sort1 li:last');
        if ($("#sort1 li").length > 3) {
            $("#sort2").append("<li class='panel panel-default' id='set_" + li.attr("id") + "' class='ui-state-default'>" + $("#" + li.attr("id")).text() + "</li>");
            $('#sort1 li:last').remove();
        }
    },
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    appendTo: 'body'
}).disableSelection();

$('#sort2').sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    appendTo: 'body'
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Marlon, não percebí bem o problema. Você quer poder movimentar elementos entre os dois campos? Neste momento dá para movimentar de cima para o de baixo.

Comment: Isto mesmo @Sergio. O problema é que quando sai de uma lista para outra o elemento que está sendo movimentando some. pois o jscrollpane faz algumas coisa para esconder o conteúdo e mostra somente o que deve ser mostrado.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uns testes na sua página e a unica solução que vejo (e testei) é adicionar uma `div` extra com ambos os `<fieldset class="linhaIndicador">` dentro dela.

Esta nova div terá `overflow: hidden;` e será ela que esconde o `overflow` do segundo `fieldset`. Assim esse segundo fieldset não terá `overflow: hidden`em nenhum elemento exceto o `.jspContainer` onde deverá ter `overflow-y: scroll`. Você tinha adicionado uma barra de scroll própria certo? Com esta solução pode tirar essa barra.

Com essas alterações deu-me isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]